# Creating multiple array using function "each" from jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, each

I'm trying to make this:

```
myArray = [
  [value1,value2,value3],
  [value1,value2,value3],
  [value1,value2,value3]
];
```

Using the function each() from jQuery, but I'm stuck even though seeing examples on the web :/ Help.

```
$('myRepeatingTag').each(function(){

  //I want to increment myArray[] here with many new values/subvalues

});
```

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for `myArray.push([new_value1, value2, value3])`?

Comment: What are you stuck on?  This should in theory be somewhat straightforward with the `push()` method

Comment: Where are the values coming from?

Comment: They come from a XML, @Andy.

Comment: You should include that information in your question. What information do you want to add to the repeating tag? The more information we have, the better we can help. Is your repeating tag actually tags that have the same class, for example. It's difficult to tell from your question exactly what you're stuck on.

Comment: Sorry. I have a XML with repeating tags which have other tags inside. I can loop through them and get the values of each one, I just need to store these values in that array outside of the each() function. Looks like the "push" thing will help. I will try, @Andy

Comment: Have you considered using a for loop rather than an each?

Comment: what does your html structure look like?

Comment: You need to show (a specimen of) your mark-up, and the desired result that should be derived from said mark-up; please see the "[MCVE]" guidelines.

Comment: I could fix this problem, guys. Thank you very much for the help. The PUSH thing helped. it was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer here, as a friend said above, is to use

```
myArray.push([new_value1, value2, value3])
```

to store new arrays inside the main array.